# Print top 5% values in a file

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I would like to print highest 5% values in column two, which i am able to do it in excel, but i would like to print the top 5% values to a new file. i have searched for similar questions but i could find suggestion to print only top 5 values. appreciate your time and help.

thank you 
kp

```
file.txt

X1 h
382 15325,3
385 15446,4
386 16501,5
446 16480
460 16467,7
534 16437,2
762 16433,7
779 16400,6
783 16398
828 16376,4
918 16319,4

x2 H   
52214 3966,33
52291 3993,4
53165 3500,57
53684 3071,67
54902 2169,83
54921 1968,9
55457 1943,98
55458 903,539
55459 609,993
55460 621,414
55461 553,236
55470 535,005
55472 298,251
55473 298,251
55474 298,251
55475 302,34
55559 371,47
55614 466,165
55679 406,352
55735 426,36

X3 H 
191773 178,645
191775 183,613
191780 193,663
191820 202,933
191838 188,988
191845 175,414
191867 167,791
191880 166,49
191883 170,456
191895 165,781
191900 154,362
191902 177,768
191914 175,431
191916 168,532
191918 163,291
191919 170,911
```

expected output (top 5%)

```
386 16501,5
446 16480
```

Comment: Top 5% in terms of number of entries or in terms of "highest value=100% => range 95% to 100%"

Comment: also, give a smaller input sample with expected output for clarity

Comment: @Fiximan in terms of "highest value=100% => range 95% to 100%".

Comment: @Sundeep i have edited the question with expected output.

Comment: assuming column two means only `16501` and not `16501,5`...  then `16480` would be `99.87%`, `16467` would be `99.79%` and so on?

Comment: @Sundeep you are right. 16501,5 has decimal so it doesn't matter if its  16501

Comment: The problem is still not specified properly. If the highest value is 100%, that's great; but what is 0%? Is zero 0%? Or is the lowest value 0%? When you say "range", that refers to the span from the lowest value to the highest value, not to 0 to the highest value!

Answer (score 2):

One difficulty with `awk` is that `awk` only deals with period as a decimal separator.

To report values that are at least 95% of the highest value (as requested in your comment to your own question), you'd do:

```
awk '{v = $2; gsub(",", ".", v); v += 0}
     !second_pass {
        if (v >= max || !started) {max = v; started=1}
        next
     }
     v >= 95 * max / 100' file second_pass=1 file
```

Which gives:

```
386 16501,5
446 16480
460 16467,7
534 16437,2
762 16433,7
779 16400,6
783 16398
828 16376,4
918 16319,4
```

If you wanted the top 5% of the lines with highest values (I'd expect you'd want to ignore the lines that don't contain a value like those `X3 H` ones), I think I'd use `perl` instead.

```
perl -lane 'if ($F[1] =~ /\d/) {push @v, ($F[1] =~ y/,/./r); push @l, $_}
            END {
              print for (map {$l[$_]}
                        sort {$v[$b] <=> $v[$a]}
                        (0..$#v))[0..($#v+1)*5/100-1]
            }' file
```

Which gives:

```
386 16501,5
446 16480
```

Answer (score 1):

[TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr) Lisp [awk](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-000264BC) macro, surrounded by other code:

```
(let* ((data (build
               (awk ((set rec (regsub #/,/ "." rec))
                     (fconv - r))
                 ([f 1] (add (list [f 1] orec))))))
       (n (length data)))
  (mapdo (opip second put-line)
         [[sort data > first] (trunc (* 5 0..n) 100)]))
```

Legend: [`let*`](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-013AF20B), [`build`](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-02ACB8CE), [`awk`](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-012F3A2C), [`rec`, `orec`](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-0003ED2C), [`fconv`](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-018CCE37), [`mapdo`](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-03A943EE), [`opip`](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-01937C5A).

Run:

```
$ txr top5.tl file.txt
386 16501,5
446 16480
```

This shows how when the Awk paradigm is a Lisp macro, it can be easily embedded in other constructs. Here it occurs inside a `build` form which establishes an environment for building a list. The `(add ...)` macro inside `build` adds to a hidden list, which is returned when `(build ...)` finishes executing (the inner `awk` job is done).

The list we build up is a list of pairs. The first element of each pair is the floating-point value. The second element is a string: the verbatim original awk record, obtained from the `orec` variable. When we sort the data, we use the first element of each pair as the sort key, and use descending order via the `>` function. When we print the first 5% of the sorted data, we map it through the functional pipeline `(opip second put-line)` that selects the second element of each pair (the original record) and passes it to `put-line`.

The expression `(trunc (* 5 0..n) 100)` is taking advantage of a new TXR feature: namely that [ranges support arithmetic](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-01884DC2). We take the range `0..n` which represents the span of the entire data list, and multiply this range by 5, then divide (using truncating integer division) by 100. This gives us a range from zero to 5%.

Since the lower zero endpoint is unaffected, we can do this without range arithmetic by operating on `n` and then forming a range: `0..(trunc (* 5 n) 100)`. There is no advantage when the lower endpoint is zero.

However, suppose we want to change the code to get the second 5 percentile. Then the range arithmetic is simpler: `(trunc (* 5 (+ 0..n n)) 100)`.  We just add `n` to the `0..n` range (which displaces it from [0, n) to [n, 2n)) and then do the shrinking to 5% as before: times 5, truncate by 100.

Answer (score 0):

This worked with the sample file

```
sort -gk 2,2 file.txt | tail -n2
446 16480
386 16501,5
```

As for determining the *top %5* that takes some extra logic. This takes the newline count in the file and multiplies it by .05, with a scale of 0 to eliminate decimals.

```
sort -gk 2,2 file | tail -n$(bc <<<"scale=0; ($(wc -l < file)*.05)/1" | cut -d\. -f1)
446 16480
386 16501,5
```